# Get SPS and PPS from h264 encoded video in JAVA

Tags: java, h.264

I'm a bit stuck on a question actually and i reaaly hope that someone can help me with this issue.

My problem is as follows :
I have a live usb camera with which i'm encoding only the video in h264 in order to send it with RTP over the network to a receiver (my receiver here for test purposes is Ekiga).
After having encoded only the video in h264, i have a byte array.

Now with this byte array, i want to extract the SPS and PPS. I want to get these information for me to be able to send the following sequence when sending frames to the receiver :
SPS => PPS => FRAME 1 (coded slice of an IDR picture) => FRAME 2 (non coded slice of an IDR picture) => FRAME 3 (non coded slice of an IDR picture) => and so on ...

How can i extract those information and i want a JAVA library which can help me? (JCODEC nop docs??!!)

Thanks for your help.
Ronnie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your encoder. If it is producing annex b stream the sps/pps are most likely the first and second Nalus. Unless it is also producing access unit delimiters in which case it will be second and third.  If it is not producing annex b then this data will need to be obtained from the encoders API another way. Either way you will need to parse the stream. You can see more details here.

[Possible Locations for Sequence/Picture Parameter Set(s) for H.264 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream/24890903#24890903)

One more thing a NALU is NOT the same thing as a frame. A frame can be made up of Many NALs.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help and answer. Well, my researches and works continue (i'm a newbie in this domain) and i have been able to transmit my video to the receiver. The receiver here is Jitsi which i'm using for test purposes.

I've seen too the link which you provided me and from it, i did understand many things which weren't totally clear.

Now, my actual problem is with the quality of the video i am receiving in Jitsi. In fact, i'm using Xuggler for encoding my orginal video (streaming from my webcam) to H264 format. When Xuggler encode my video, i can now see the correct SPS, PPS and SEI headers and you are right i can notice too many NALs which make up my frame to be transmitted over the network.

I think that it would be better to use another library than Xuggler but there comes my real problem. JCodec, there's no documentations and from what i have read, it's a bit slow in processing H264 videos.

Can you please guide me in the choice of a good library which can help me in encoding and decoding H264 video streams?

Does anyone know a library in Java which can do that for me and some documentations associated with this library?

Thanks for your help.
Ronnie